# Is there a general term for the phenomena of an object being the union of all its subsets with certain properties?

Tags: functional-analysis, terminology

In a Linear Analysis course I'm taking, a homework question involves proving that every nonempty closed convex set $C$ in a real normed space is equal to the intersection of all closed half-spaces $H$ that are supersets of $C$.

The general pattern here is a variation on "every set $C$ with certain properties is the union of all subsets $H$ of $C$ with (a possibly different suite of) certain properties," but with intersections and supersets instead of unions and subsets.

This seems closely related to the widely applied concept of closure under union (c.q. intersection) found in a variety of forms in matters involving open sets in topology, closed linear subspaces in functional analysis, several kinds of ideals in ring theory, and many more topics elsewhere in mathematics. The difference is that for closure, the subsets (c.q. supersets) $H$ considered are exactly those that have the same structure and properties as the original object $C$, while the phenomenon I'm interested in allows for unions (c.q. intersections) to range over subsets with other properties than this original $C$.

My question is whether there exists an established (or at least attested) term for this phenomenon, or if my description here is the best we can hope for.

Comment: For closures and intersections, this could be a starting point https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_operator . I found it illuminating, when I came across this notion.